# Objcopy getting object file 64 bit binaries

Tags: windows, gcc, objcopy

I use objcopy on windows 10 to embed my dll inside an exe and load it. It runs fine with 32 bit compilation with a 32 bits binary dll file as i am getting no errors loading my dll.

```
objcopy --prefix-symbol=_ --input-target binary --output-target pe-i386 --binary-architecture i386 somedll.dll somedll.o
```

How can I set objcopy arguments so that I can get a 64 bit binaries object file? If it is not possible with `objcopy` is there any alternatives to it ? My dll doesnt get loaded when i compile it to be 64 bits, and if i try to compile the executable with the object file as in 64 bits it returns error saying that my object file is not compatible with 64 bit compilation.

so during gcc compilation for example, i have to do

```
gcc -m32 Myfile.c somedll.o -o output.exe
```

if i remove `-m32` it doesnt compile because somedll.o is set to 32 bits even if it was 64 bits as in dll, so thats why my `LoadLibrary()` function can not load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the best results with this argument.

```
objcopy --prefix-symbol=_ --input-target binary --output-target pe-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386:x86-64 some64.dll some64.o
```

Switching `pe-i386` to `pe-x86-64` and `i386` to `i386:x86-64` enabled me to embed my 64 bit dll into my executable without running into any binary compatibility problems. It works well on windows.